# CSS line is not wrapping inside table

Tags: css, google-chrome, internet-explorer-9

I faced the problem with `white-space: pre-line` in my layout. When I wrap content in a `div` element it works just fine, but when I replace `div` with `table` text is no longer wrapping. This is only small part just to show the case. In original code it would be hard to replace this outer table. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            border: 1px dashed red;
            font-size: 12px;
            font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
            margin: 0 auto !important;
            padding: 10px;
            width: 600px;
        }

        .document-preview {
            border-spacing: 0;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .document-preview .content-details-row {
            padding: 0 2px 0 162px;
            position: relative;
            white-space: nowrap;
            z-index: 1;
        }

        .document-preview .content-details-row span:first-child {
            display: block;
            float: left;
            margin: 0 2px 0 -160px;
            overflow: hidden;
            width: 160px;
            z-index: 2;
        }

        .document-preview .content-details-row span:first-child:after {
            content: "..............................................................................";
            font-weight: lighter;
            font-size: 10px;
            letter-spacing: 2px;
        }

        .document-preview .content-details-row .content-details-value {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 100%;
            z-index: 2;
        }

        .document-preview .content-details-row .content-details-value > div {
            white-space: pre-line;
            word-wrap: break-word;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <table class="document-preview"><tbody><tr><td>
        <div class="content-details-row">
            <span>Label:</span> 
            <span class="content-details-value">
                <div>Doesn't work: Something something AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</div>
            </span>
        </div>
    </td></tr></tbody></table>

    <hr />

    <div class="document-preview">
        <div class="content-details-row">
            <span>Label:</span> 
            <span class="content-details-value">
                <div>Works: Something something AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</div>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/UPXzt/1/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this style to your page

```
table {
    table-layout: fixed;

}
```

sample:
http://jsfiddle.net/UPXzt/10/

Answer (score 0):

Try this [demo](http://jsbin.com/erewix/1/edit)

just add width to the div

```
.document-preview .content-details-row .content-details-value > div 
{
width: 430px;
white-space: pre-wrap !important;
word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: I can't add `width`, because content should scale with browser window.

Comment: but you have width to your body in px then how come the table be scale with browser window ?

Comment: also i have edited that with table layout see demo  http://jsbin.com/erewix/8/ try scaling the browser window

Comment: This is example to show the problem. As I wrote this is only part of the layout.